# swift creating and passing a closure

Tags: swift

I've this method signature, and having issues on how to create and pass the closure to it.

The signature of the method looks like this.

```
func getProduct(_ catalog: String, closure: (String) -> Int) -> Bool {
    return false;
}
```

Question is, how to call it? I've following attempt.

```
var result = getProduct("foo", closure: (name: String) -> return 4);
```

it says

> Expected type before '->'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this is Swift: No trailing semicolons.

You can call the function in three ways, the parameter name `param` is arbitrary:

1. Standard syntax

   ```
   let result = getProduct("Foo", closure: { param in
       return Int(param) ?? 0
   })
   ```
2. Trailing closure syntax (this is the way code completion suggests)

   ```
   let result = getProduct("Foo") { param in
       return Int(param) ?? 0
   }
   ```
3. Separate declaration of the closure

   ```
   let closure : (String) -> Int = { param in
       return Int(param) ?? 0
   }

   let result = getProduct("Foo", closure: closure)
   ```

In Swift 5.1+ you can even omit the `return` statements (`{ param in Int(param) ?? 0 }`)

Comment: I see, the syntax involves `in` keyword when it come to creating a closure with arguments